# SonarQube UpdateCenter behind firewall

Tags: sonarqube

I have a local SonarQube installation behind a firewall. Because of this the Update Center does not work wit availible updates.
I need to know what I need to open in my firewall to make this work.

Regards Magnus

Comment: You have to open `SonarQube` port. Default is `9000` if you have not changed it

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. So SonarQube user port 9000 to access external content through the update page and not only internally, is that correct? Regards Magnus

Answer (score 1):

You have to open `SonarQube` port.
*If you have not changed the `default` settings in `sonar.properties`:*

```
sonar.web.port=9000
```

*Then the default port is **9000***

> So SonarQube user port 9000 to access external content through the
>   update page and not only internally, is that correct?

***Yes***. This will tell firewall that connections coming from this port are allowed to pass through it.

***note:*** based on different cases, you may need to open `webport`also(**8080**)